# How to send a value from a select statement in MVC controller to Viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I want to return just a value to ViewBag with the LINQ query below

```
var myCompanyName = (from c in db.Companies
                     where c.CompanyId == CompanyID
                     select c.CompanyName).ToString();
ViewBag.myCompanyName = myCompanyName;
```

In my MVC controller but I get the following output in my View.

```
SELECT [Extent1].[CompanyName] AS [CompanyName] FROM [dbo].[Companies] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[CompanyId] = @p__linq__0 Company Name from Controller Action
```

The result ViewBag expected from view bag should be something like: CompanyName XYZ. Please how do I make this right?

Comment: Remove the `.ToString();` from your query. Note also your query is returning a collection of strings - I'm guessing you might want `.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have removed the ToString() from the query but I still have `SELECT [Extent1].[CompanyName] AS [CompanyName] FROM [dbo].[Companies] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[CompanyId] = @p__linq__0`  as my result.

Comment: `ViewBag.myCompanyName = db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CompanyId == CompanyID);`

Comment: Add the `.FirstOrDefault()` (in place of `.ToString()`) so you materialize the query and return a single value

Comment: @ramiramilu : I get this error outputted to ViewBag
`System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Company_502FF39CE4EC198B3C72847CDDF4F702895AD59A1104D7696BDB0D21E55E6CB1`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: This worked pretty fine...thanks a bunch! How do I vote you for the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not materializing your query, and I suspect you want to return a single value (not `IEnumerable<string>`) so you need to replace `.ToString()` with `.FirstOrDefault()`

```
var myCompanyName = (from c in db.Companies
                     where c.CompanyId == CompanyID
                     select c.CompanyName).FirstOrDefault();
ViewBag.myCompanyName = myCompanyName;
```

or if you did want a collection of `string`, then it would be `.ToList()`

Comment: Hi. My friends recommended you to me in Asp.Net MVC. I have one [question in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273517/best-practice-for-persisting-user-state-in-special-kind-of-asp-net-mvc-applicati). Could you please help me as it is very urgent. And I will really be helpful for your help.